# Error while connecting Excel with Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, database-connection, excel-365

I am trying to connect Excel will Oracle DB.
I have already installed the Oracle client in my system (version: Oracle 11.2.0.3.0_64-bit).

The process which I am following is:

[image]

Then I got below message.

[image]
Then I clicked "OK"

Then I entered the server details and clicked "OK" to connect.

Then I got below error.

[image]

I retried but every time same issue.

I followed the same connection process in Power BI, there I am able to connect successfully, but the issue is only coming in Excel.

what could be the reason and how I can fix it?

Comment: Please post the *text* of your process and error messages, not images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message if your Oracle Client that is installed is 64-bit, your version of Microsoft Office that is installed is 32-bit.

You can check the version of Office that's installed by going to File > Account > About Excel. In the pop-up, it will indicate if it is 32-bit.

[image: Excel screenshot]

You can correct the error by installing the version of the Oracle Client (32-bit or 64-bit) that matches your Microsoft Office installation.